# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in Android Receive Sms App

Tags: android

Facing the Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo problem while launching the SMS Receiver Application. Could any tell me what i am doing wrong????

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.raja.receivesms"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ReceivesmsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".ReceivesmsActivity"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /></manifest>
```

And class file as follows ReceivesmsActivity.java

```
    package com.raja.receivesms;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ReceivesmsActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private static final String TAG = "Message recieved";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
     SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
     String str = "";            
     if (bundle != null)
     {
         Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
         msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
         for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
             msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
             str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
             str += " :";
             str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
             str += "\n";        
         }
         Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }                         
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BroadcastReceiver i.e ReceivesmsActivity  and Activity i.e ReceivesmsActivity is with same name may be causing problem so just change to different name register your sms receiver as:

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceivesmsBroadcast"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

and in code create a class ReceivesmsBroadcast.java:

```
public class ReceivesmsBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private static final String TAG = "Message recieved";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
///     your code go here      

 }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, i will try this method. But one question, my intention to create this app is i want to create it as service, which means even if mobile switched off and restarted automatically this application should trigger and work. Is it possible in your case?

Comment: yes it's possible i will tell u first solve ur current problem

Comment: for starting your application after switched off or reboot you will need to register an ON_BOOT_RECEIVE Broadcast Receiver for your Application in same way as you are currently registering for SMS_RECIVED.if you post this as new question then i will answer step by step to start your sercie on boot

Comment: Ok thanks... i will try the first solution from you... then i will post a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: working like a charm ... thanks..... Now i want to create it as like service... could you help me plz.... link for the question is
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774150/sms-receiver-as-a-service