# SMS Receiver as a Service

Tags: android

I have created SMS Receiver app... but i want to create it as an service, it should run in the background (i.e no separate UI for this app, want to work like alarm app) and even if mobile restarts it automatically starts... could any one help on this?

My previous SMS Receiver app code was here 
[Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in Android Receive Sms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769107/unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-in-android-receive-sms-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it should run in the background

Your existing `BroadcastReceiver` for the (undocumented) `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` already runs in the background.

> and even if mobile restarts it automatically starts

Your existing `BroadcastReceiver` for the (undocumented) `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` already is available after the device reboots.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your service to run at phone startup, you should simply declare a broadcast receiver with this intent filter:

```
    <receiver android:name="MyStartupIntentReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action
android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the broadcast receiver onReceive() method, just launch your service:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("myPackage.MyService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);

}
```

And be sure to link the service in your manifest with the same name of the intent you launch in the broadcast receiver:

```
<service android:name="MyService">
<intent-filter>
<action
android:name="myPackage.MyService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare has said there is no need to actually have a "Service" run in the background for you to receiver SMS broadcasts, if registered in your manifest properly your BroadcastReceiver with "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" as the intent filter will fire every time an SMS is received no other action required.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, from that broadcast receiver you can then do you work via an actual Service, or probably a better option would to be to use an IntentService. This is because the thread used for the broadcast will get killed shortly after starting, so you should not do any extensive work in it.

It is generally recommend to not use an actual "Service" unless explicitly required....BUT if that is what you need then you need Davide should get you the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare , Davide. I will try this and let you people know